# Why is this anime called "Shuffle!"?

Tags: shuffle

Why is this anime given the title, "Shuffle!"?

Link:
https://myanimelist.net/anime/79/Shuffle

Are there any significant reasons?

Answer (score 2):

There is no definitive answer as Navel never made a public statement about it, but probably because there are different races in the game: humans, gods and devils. All coming together in the main character's school. So a shuffle of races, of sorts.